# createPeerAdminCard.sh not running

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/develop/installing/development-tools

As i was following this and reached the step to Start and Stop Hyperledger Fabric, i was told to run `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`
as i run this, i get an error as follows:

```
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Cannot use Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34 version of composer with this level of fabric
```

Please provide support Thanks!

link shows my current versions of composer
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDM2M.png

Comment: What version of Composer are you using? `composer -v`  
and What version of Fabric are you using ?  `docker ps`

Comment: @RThatcher i've updated the post with a link to everything you enquired for. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder - do you have 'composer' installed rather than 'composer-cli' ?

Comment: @RThatcher yes i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to uninstall the 'other composer' and then install composer-cli with -g as per the Composer Dev Environment documents.

There have been a few releases of Hyperledger Composer in the last couple of weeks with Breaking Changes and different Hyperledger Fabric versions required.  Please check the release notes for the latest version information:
[Release Notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases)