# Hyperledger Fabric: Issues with composer version

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am new to the hyperledger composer. To install it, I follow the steps mentioned here: [Hyperledger Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)
However, I am facing the following issue:

**Error:** Cannot use Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required

I would also like to add that I have checked the composer version `composer -v` which is: Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34

P.S I can see a similar post [createPeerAdminCard.sh not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632590/createpeeradmincard-sh-not-running). However, I couldn't solve my problem yet. It would be great if someone could explain " uninstall the 'other composer' and then install composer-cli with -g as per the Composer Dev Environment documents." I have already followed the guidelines stated in [Updating components](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/update-dev-env.html)

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would like to point out that Hyperledger Composer is end of life, you should not be using it except maybe to get a general idea around the concept of digital assets and not as a learning tool for hyperledger fabric.

In your case the problem is you have not installed hyperledger composer, you have installed another tool called composer by the looks of things.

Answer (score 0):

To start with Hyperledger composer, its better to start with installing pre-reqs using this:
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/prereqs-ubuntu.sh

chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh

Then Simply running: npm install -g composer-cli@0.19

You can refer: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools